# Two Columns with Similar Data in Excel How to Match One Columnn and Return The New Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vba

I have columns in excel

```
ORDER NUMBER   Order Paid Date    Order Total    Order Date  
A1=1             B1= jan 1           c1= $1            d1= Dec 1
A2=2             B2=jan 2            c2= $1            d2= Dec 1
A3=3             B3=jan 3            c3= $1            d3= Dec 1
```

Then I have another column

```
ORDER NUMBER   Shipment Date
I1=1          J1= Jan 5
I2=2          J2= jan 6
I3=3          J3= jan 7
```

How do math the order number (I1) to the order number in A1 and add it to the next column so it would look like this

```
ORDER NUMBER   Order Paid Date    Order Total       Order Date   Shipment Date
   A1=1       B1= jan 1           c1= $1            d1= Dec 1    E1= JAN 5
   A2=2       B2=jan 2            c2= $1            d2= Dec 1    E1= JAN 6
   A3=3       B3=jan 3            c3= $1            d3= Dec 1    E1= JAN 7
```

I have tried Vlookup =VLOOKUP(A2,$J$1:$K$14075,2,FALSE) with the proper columns but that doesnt work, is there any other formula that would?

Thanks so much I greatly appreciate all the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say proper columns but the sample data you provided says you have them in columns I and J?

I would use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$I:$J,2,FALSE)
```

`$I:$J` covers the two columns completely.

Comment: What I meant is where it belongs I and J and it returns a value that I have no idea where its coming from, **correction it was returning proper value but I didnt format the cell for the date

Comment: @user1771351 Ahh, yes, that happens when you see 41483 or something and you're like "Wha..?" xD I've got that many times myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have your Order date and shipment date data in columns I & J, but are running your VLOOKUP in J&K - try changing the range to $I$1:$J$14075 and see if that helps you.